# Drag items onto draggable object

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am currently developing a wordpress plugin. This plugin requires to drag certain items onto an image. The layout is like this:

[image]

And i need to save the points that are dragged onto the picture into the database. I also need the ability to edit the points or remove the points.
Does anybody knows a good method of achieving this?

Kind regards,
Jack

Edit:

Maybe i'm being a little bit vague about this, but all i need is suggestions.. I do not need people to write code for me.

Comment: Do you have to drag? Or can you select object and just click a point on image?

Comment: That last option would be ideal. But both options are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search gave me:

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=160798
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/07/identifying-locating-mouse-position-in.html
[jQuery get mouse position within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249648/jquery-get-mouse-position-within-an-element)
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-snippet-relative-mouse-position

My suggestion is that  `onmouseup()` you get the co-ordinates and store them.

A bit more googling and I found this answer:
[Alternatives to trigger('mouseup') to stop dragging programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927020/alternatives-to-triggermouseup-to-stop-dragging-programmatically)

Maybe this will help you.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot you are asking eh, you can't expect us to write it for you but we can point your nose in the right direction :)

I suggest you start looking at the [jQuery UI draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) (and of course [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) too), it offers quite a flexible drag and drop implementation.

Comment: I am not expecting that either. To point me in the right direction is exactly what i need. I am just asking for suggestions, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the `jquery ui draggable plugin`

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/